# Code in my function retrieving data from my realtime database does not trigger the other window.alerts

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

The code below Works up to the point of function `testValue()` but then the code within this function does not trigger.

```
$("#orderTF").click(function(){
    var db = firebase.database();
    var ref = db.ref("MyCanteen/Schools/Cross&Passion/CanOrder");
    ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      var value = snapshot.val();
      window.alert(value);
      function testValue(value,errorObject){
          if(value == "false"){
          window.alert("the code works"); 
          }else{
          window.alert(errorObject.code); 
          }
      } 
    }, 
    function (errorObject) {
  window.alert("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});

  });
```

I tested the code in jsLint and it all appears to work.

Comment: testValue is never being called. Also, please don't put false inside quotes. that is a string not a boolean data type.

Comment: btw jsLint does not "test" your code, it just flags certain (potential) issues in advance. Linting tools are no substitute for actual testing.

Comment: False was intentionally a string for testing purposes at the moment, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#orderTF").click(function(){
    var db = firebase.database();
    var ref = db.ref("MyCanteen/Schools/Cross&Passion/CanOrder");
    ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      var value = snapshot.val();
      window.alert(value);
      testValue(value, errorObject);
    }, 
    function (errorObject) {
  window.alert("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});

  });


function testValue(value,errorObject){
    if(value == "false"){
        window.alert("the code works"); 
        }else{
            window.alert(errorObject.code); 
         }
    } 
}
```